# How to get Max() Value using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have two table `cost` and `history` table, both table have the same field name `AccountingMonth`, i would like to get Latest `AccountingMonth` from the two table

```
   var accountingMonthCost= await _context.Cost
                       .Select(ic => new ProductDTO
                       {
                           LatestCostMonth = ic.AccountingMonth
                       })
                       .ToListAsync();
```

History table

```
      var accountingMonthHistory = await _context.history
                       .Select(ic => new ProductDTO
                       {
                           LatestCostMonth = ic.AccountingMonth
                       })
                       .ToListAsync();
```

I need help combine AccountingMonth in both table and get the latest Accounting Month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat both together and ask for the max.

```
var latestAccountingMonth = await _context.Cost.Select(c=>c.AccountingMonth)
  .Concat(_context.history.Select(c=>c.AccountingMonth))
  .MaxAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! but i get this error `System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.`

Comment: What type is AccountingMonth?

Comment: Its  [MonthYYYYMM] [char](8) NOT NULL,

Comment: That should map to a string in C#, which is IComparable, so I'm not sure where you are getting the error.